# Is AngularJS the right tool for a new project that covers various platforms with different UI?

Tags: angularjs

We're getting started on a new application that will run on several platforms (web, mobile, tablets etc). The goal is keep the models and controllers the same for all the platforms. Only the views will be changing. For example, if I have `Roles view (and RolesCtrl)` and `Persons view (and PersonCtrl)` on different pages (roles view redirects to persons page with role id as query string or something) on one platform, these two views might be combined into a single page (role id should not transfer to person page but to another view on the same page) on a different platform. I understand I can have separate divs and keeping the controllers intact, but since the UI flow is different for different platforms, how can that be handled? Is it feasible to keep the controllers unchanged?

Is this the right approach? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By extacting shared data and logic (e.g. UI flows) that should differ between platforms into services, I've been able to do this with a fair amount of success.

Comment: I keep hearing about Services over and over again, but couldn't quite wrap my head around the concept. Could you please create a simple jsfiddle on how you changed the UI flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest proving this out by creating a small project to implement some piece of functionality backed by a service that AngularJS will communicate with.

It sounds like you might have some behind the scenes complications here. I would suggest that if you do use AngularJS to make sure all of the developers are making their HTTP communications done through AngularJS and not try to go work around it.

From my short experience with AngularJS I think it would work fine and may actually make things simpler because of it's easy single application model.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually putting together a POC to verify if this will work. You're right in stating that there are complications behind the scenes. The piece that fetches the data is already in place. The controllers will need to just call API's and use them.

Comment: If you are calling services that are not serving the AngularJS files themselves, you may need to make sure the service has JSONP functionality. If your using Jersey on the back end it shouldn't be a problem.